# What's the expected behavior with BIND slave that's been offline for some time?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

We have a situation where a BIND slave server was not able to write any zone data to the file system. When this server was rebooted and BIND restarted it started with an older version of the zone files than what was currently on the master.

During this time it was able to receive IXFR transfers from the master, it just couldn't persist these changes to the HDD.

This got me wondering about what is the expected behavior with a BIND server? It seems like a bit of a design flaw that it wouldn't do some checking with its master, prior to entering service.

For reference this is the version of bind on the slave side:

```
$ rpm -q bind
bind-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.2.x86_64
```

I did find this reference:

- [Tuning your BIND configuration effectively for zone transfers (particularly with many frequently-updated zones)](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00726)

Which states the following:

> #### Zone notifies and refreshes
>
> Apart from when a server is restarted, or when rndc commands are used to force a zone transfer, there are two
>   mechanisms that cause slave servers to check whether or not their copy
>   of a zone is current.  The process of checking and updating is called
>   a zone refresh :

I interpret this as BIND not doing anything special when in its start up phase.

Comment: As far as I know upon start-up Bind will check for each slave zone if the cached version of that zone is still valid by requesting the SOA record from the defined master(s) and validating the zone version number. If it can't contact the master server(s)  it should only use the stale cached version of the slave zone file only for as long as the SOA `expire` value allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, didn't read all the docs completely. There's a paragraph that states the following on the same page:

> When a server is restarted, it sends out notifications for the zones
>   that it has loaded (in case they have been updated while it was not
>   running).  Similarly, when loading zones that are slaved, a
>   newly-restarted named will initiate a refresh for each zone (using
>   jittered time intervals so that all refreshes are not initiated
>   concurrently).

So from this it sounds like the BIND slaves will send out a notification to the master and then coordinate IXFRs to catch up and begin serving updated zone information.

Comment: Some slight nuances: as far as I know the NOTIFY will only be sent for each slave zone **after** both a SOA check indicates that Bind needed to do a zone transfer and completed that successfully. The default [`notify`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#notify) behavior is that a slave does **not**  send notifications the master, (the name server in the SOA record) nor to itself, but instead only to all the *other* NS records found in the zone file.  Additional notifications will be sent when configured with  [`also-notify`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#also-notify)

Comment: *"When a server is restarted, it sends out notifications for the zones that it has loaded (in case they have been updated while it was not running)"* - that is, *I think*  only the case for the zones where the server is the master.

Comment: Notifications are from master to slave. This is just to speed up default mechanism that makes the slave only attempt to connect to master after "refresh" interval as stored in SOA record (or overriden in configuration). IXFR/AXFR is orthogonal of that, as IXFR is used to synchronize faster by exchanging less data.

Comment: "Notifications are from master to slave. " typically, because they are the ones useful. Slave to slave ones have little use. Specifically since it can be spoofed or lost.